# Gauss-Seidel method in Python3, at the beginning of every cycle why I have to set to zero the array with most recent solutions?

Tags: python-3.6, numerical-methods

In the following code for the [Gauss Seidel method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method), I enter one given matrix `A`. The result seems to be correct, but when I comment the vector `x1` at the beginning of the `while`, I obtain an unwanted result:

For example, before the assignment `x0=x1`, when `k=1`, `x0` is equal to `x1`; instead `x0` when `k=1`, would be equal to `x1` when `k=0`.

Consequently, the `norm(x1-x0)` is always 0, after the first `while`. I don't know why it happens.

This is the code, you can see the wanted and unwanted output below:

```py
   def GaussSeidel(A,b):
       # dimension of the non-singular matrix
       n = len(A)

       # def. max iteration and criterions
       Kmax = 100;
       tol  = 1.0e-4;
       btol = la.norm(b)*tol


       x0   = np.zeros(n)
       k    = 0 ;
       stop = False
       x1   = np.empty(n)

       while not(stop) and k < Kmax:
           print ("begin while with k =", k)
           x1 = np.zeros(n)
           for i in range(n):          # rows of A
               x1[i] = ( b[i] - np.dot(A[i,0:i], x1[0:i]) - np.dot(A[i,i+1:n], x0[i+1:n]) ) / A[i,i]
               print("x1 =", x1)

           r    = b - np.dot(A,x1)
           stop = (la.norm(r) < btol) and (la.norm(x1-x0) < tol)
           print("end of for i \n")
           print("x0 =", x0)
           print("btol = %e \t; la.norm(r) = %e \t; tol = %e \t; la.norm(x1-x0) = %e; stop = %s " % (btol, la.norm(r), tol, la.norm(x1-x0), stop))
           x0   = x1
           print("x0 =", x0, end='\n')
           print("end of current while \n\n")
           k    = k + 1

       if not(stop): # or if k >= Kmax
           print('Not converges in %d iterations' % Kmax)

       return x1, k

   import numpy        as np
   import numpy.linalg as la
   import time

   A = np.array( [
          [  3, -0.1, -0.2],
          [0.1,    7, -0.3],
          [0.3, -0.2,   10]
       ], dtype='f')

   b = np.array( [7.85, -19.3, 71.4] )

   xsol = la.solve(A,b)

   start    = time.time()
   x, k     = GaussSeidel(A,b)
   ending   = time.time()
   duration = ending-start
   err      = la.norm(xsol-x)
   print('Iter.=%d  duration=%f  err=%e' % (k,duration,err))
```

Wanted output: - As you can see `x0` contains the `x1` of of the previous while iteration

```
begin while with k = 0
x1 = [2.61666667 0.         0.        ]
x1 = [ 2.61666667 -2.79452381  0.        ]
x1 = [ 2.61666667 -2.79452381  7.00560952]
end of for i 

x0 = [0. 0. 0.]
la.norm(r) = 2.382271e+00   ; la.norm(x1-x0) = 7.983412e+00; stop = False 
x0 = [ 2.61666667 -2.79452381  7.00560952]
end of current while 


begin while with k = 1
x1 = [2.99055651 0.         0.        ]
x1 = [ 2.99055651 -2.49962467  0.        ]
x1 = [ 2.99055651 -2.49962467  7.00029081]
end of for i 

x0 = [ 2.61666667 -2.79452381  7.00560952]
la.norm(r) = 2.847092e-02   ; la.norm(x1-x0) = 4.762220e-01; stop = False 
x0 = [ 2.99055651 -2.49962467  7.00029081]
end of current while 


begin while with k = 2
x1 = [3.0000319 0.        0.       ]
x1 = [ 3.0000319  -2.49998798  0.        ]
x1 = [ 3.0000319  -2.49998798  6.99999928]
end of for i 

x0 = [ 2.99055651 -2.49962467  7.00029081]
la.norm(r) = 1.288604e-04   ; la.norm(x1-x0) = 9.486833e-03; stop = False 
x0 = [ 3.0000319  -2.49998798  6.99999928]
end of current while 


begin while with k = 3
x1 = [3.00000036 0.         0.        ]
x1 = [ 3.00000036 -2.50000002  0.        ]
x1 = [ 3.00000036 -2.50000002  6.99999998]
end of for i 

x0 = [ 3.0000319  -2.49998798  6.99999928]
la.norm(r) = 1.084102e-06   ; la.norm(x1-x0) = 3.377360e-05; stop = True 
x0 = [ 3.00000036 -2.50000002  6.99999998]
end of current while 


Iter.=4  duration=0.234001  err=3.544580e-07
```

Unwanted output if I comment `x1 = np.zeros(n)` at the beginning of `while` :

```
begin while with k = 0
x1 = [2.61666667e+000 1.94626056e+227 2.04746603e+161]
x1 = [ 2.61666667e+000 -2.79452381e+000  2.04746603e+161]
x1 = [ 2.61666667 -2.79452381  7.00560952]
end of for i 

x0 = [0. 0. 0.]
la.norm(r) = 2.382271e+00   ; la.norm(x1-x0) = 7.983412e+00; stop = False 
x0 = [ 2.61666667 -2.79452381  7.00560952]
end of current while 


begin while with k = 1
x1 = [ 2.99055651 -2.79452381  7.00560952]
x1 = [ 2.99055651 -2.49962467  7.00560952]
x1 = [ 2.99055651 -2.49962467  7.00029081]
end of for i 

x0 = [ 2.99055651 -2.49962467  7.00029081]
la.norm(r) = 2.847092e-02   ; la.norm(x1-x0) = 0.000000e+00; stop = False 
x0 = [ 2.99055651 -2.49962467  7.00029081]
end of current while 


begin while with k = 2
x1 = [ 3.0000319  -2.49962467  7.00029081]
x1 = [ 3.0000319  -2.49998798  7.00029081]
x1 = [ 3.0000319  -2.49998798  6.99999928]
end of for i 

x0 = [ 3.0000319  -2.49998798  6.99999928]
la.norm(r) = 1.288604e-04   ; la.norm(x1-x0) = 0.000000e+00; stop = True 
x0 = [ 3.0000319  -2.49998798  6.99999928]
end of current while 


Iter.=3  duration=0.156000  err=3.409068e-05
```

Even if I don't assing zeros to `x1` in each cycle, the solution are computed correctly. Can you help me?

You can execute online at:
https://www.jdoodle.com/a/1h6N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what are you trying to achieve and why do you want to AVOID zeroing out `x1` if you care about what is being printed.

However, I think I see the source of confusion.
Notice, that in the following piece of code:

```
x1 = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):          # rows of A
         x1[i] = ( b[i] - np.dot(A[i,0:i], x1[0:i]) - np.dot(A[i,i+1:n], x0[i+1:n]) ) / A[i,i]
         print("x1 =", x1)
```

the `print` expression is inside the `for`-loop, while the entries of `x1` are updated one by one.
So, if you don't zero out `x1` before the `for`-loop:

- at the first `while` iteration, `x1` entries contain garbage, so the first `print` output will have a correct entry of `x1[0]` and garbage for `x1[1:]`.
- at the other `while` iterations `x1` entries would contain previous (not yet overwritten) values.

So, if you want to see the "progress inside" without confusion on data that will be overwritten, you should zero it out. Otherwise, with this particular algorithm implementation it is safe to leave it out if you don't care about the output.

Comment: I don't care about the output of `x1`, but it is important to me to show the correct norm for each `while`.

Comment: still I am not convinced why it is necessary to zeroing `x1` to obtain a correct `x0`. So I don't want to "avoid" zeroing out `x1`, but I want to comprehend why it is important to the correctness of `x0`.